# django скачать файл из бд

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Меня интересует как в джанго скачать файл из бд ? использую стандартную dbsqlite. Везде пишут как загрузить в бд но как из нее выгрузить информацию не нашел.

Comment: В базу загружаются, как правило, не файлы а данные. Обращение к базе - это и есть выгрузка. Она осуществляется, например, так: obj = model.objects.get(id=1)
Дальше вы делаете нечто с этим объектом (выгрузкой)

Comment: Плохо искали - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36394206/11214129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У меня есть БД с таблицей AddRPA
2. В этой таблице есть столбец file_protokol
3. Моя модель:

   ```
   class AddRPA(models.Model):
       process_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Наименование процесса', default="", max_length=40, db_index=True)
       operation = models.CharField("Кол-во операций в день", default="", max_length=1000)
       description = models.TextField("Описание робота", default="")
       effect = models.TextField("Эффект, ПШЕ.(общий)", default="")
       minutes = models.TextField("Высвобождение минут за одну операцию", default="")
       id_request = models.TextField("ID инициативы", default="")
       fio = models.TextField("ФИО разработчика", default="", blank=True)
       date = models.DateTimeField("Дата реализации", default=datetime.now(), blank=True)
       status = models.TextField("Статус", default="", blank=True)
       date_add = models.DateTimeField("Дата добавления", default=datetime.now(), blank=True)
       e_mail = models.TextField("E-mail", default="", blank=True)
       auto_system = models.TextField("АС", default="")
       another = models.TextField("Инфраструктурный эффект (минимизация рисковой зоны)", default="")
       file_protokol = models.FileField(verbose_name='Файл', default="", upload_to=file_path + 'docs/', blank=True)

       def __str__(self):
           return self.process_name

       class Meta:
           verbose_name = 'Заявки автоматизации'
           verbose_name_plural = 'Заявки автоматизации'
           ordering = ['-date_add']
   ```

   4. Самое главное здесь - это upload_to: необходимо указать по какому пути будет сохранятся файл. Обычно это путь, который указан в {% static %}
   5. Таким образом я беру полный путь и записываю его в file_name

      file_name = str(AddRPA.objects.get(pk=id).file_protokol)
   6. И далее обрабатываю файл. Смотрю его тип и тем самым подбираю нужные параметры для HttpResonse.

      ```
      path_download = file_name
      temp = file_name.split('/')
      file_name = temp[len(temp) -1]

      file_type = '.' + file_name.split('.')[1]

      dict_type = {'.doc': 'application/msword',
                   '.docx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                   '.dot': 'application/msword',
                   '.dotx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template',
                   '.docm': 'application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12',
                   '.dotm': 'application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12',
                   '.xls': 'application/vnd.ms-excel', '.xla': 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                   '.xlsx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                   '.xltx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template',
                   '.xlsm': 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12',
                   '.xltm': 'application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12',
                   '.xlam': 'application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12',
                   '.xlsb': 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12',
                   '.ppt': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
                   '.pot': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', '.pps': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
                   '.ppa': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
                   '.pptx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
                   '.potx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template',
                   '.ppsx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow',
                   '.ppam': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12',
                   '.pptm': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12',
                   '.potm': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12',
                   '.ppsm': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12',
                   '.mdb': 'application/vnd.ms-access', '.pdf': 'application/pdf',
                   }

      for i in dict_type:
          if i == file_type:
              file_type = dict_type[i]
              break

      if os.path.exists(path_download):
          with open(path_download, 'rb') as fl:
             response = HttpResponse(fl.read(), content_type=file_type, charset='utf-8')
              response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(urlquote(file_name))
              response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(path_download)
              return response
      raise Http404
      ```